# Printing a HashMap that contains of String and List of Objects

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I print a HashMap that containts of String and List of Objects?

```
HashMap<String, List<Object>> Map = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
```

Each object has a name and a key value so I need to get something like:

```
StringFirst = [ firstObject 15, second object 31, thirdobject 16]
StringSecond = [ fourthObject 15, fifthObject 31, sixthObject 16]

    public static class Graph {

    public class Edge extends Graph {
        String edgeName;
        int time;

        Edge(String edgeName, int time){
            this.edgeName = edgeName;
            this.time = time;
        }

        public void Out(){
            System.out.println(this.edgeName);
            System.out.println(this.time);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does  the List contain numbers 15, 31 and 16?

Comment: it doesnt work with "return Map;"

Comment: I can enter Name and Key of objects in List

Comment: Capitalized `Map` is an interface, you might be having issues with that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out for printing the map:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Edge>> e : map.entrySet()){
   for(Edge e1 : e.getValue())
      System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = "+ e1.Out());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to iterate through a map would be to use the keyset.

`for(String key: map.keyset())
{
    System.out.println(key + " = " + map.get(key));
}`

On the `.get(key)` you may need to handle it differently, or iterate through the returned list

Alternately this is functionally the same,

`for(Map.Entry e : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = "+ e.getValue());
}`

Comment: It prints as in comment i answered upper. Problem is that for each object of list i need to call method that return its name

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` if you want it to display in a different way or iterate through the returned list.